# Probability Realization

Tags: math, statistics, probability

If I have the probabilities of x, y, and z events occurring, how can I programatically realize the choosing between these three events?

Example:
Pr(x) = 0.3
Pr(y) = 0.2
Pr(z) = 0.5

I'd like a function to give me a realization of these probabilities to say I should choose y, or maybe z, etc.

Any pointers or references are appreciated, thanks.

Comment: what exactly is given to you and what are you trying to achieve? do you have P(X),P(Y),P(Z) ?  are you looking for the probability they co-occure? are they independent?

Comment: Yes, I am given the probabilities of each event.  Say object U, would like to choose between these three events, and only chooses one event.

Comment: I still don't get you, you are given the probability, and you want to choose what? can you give a specific detailed example please?

Comment: Object x would like to choose events: x, y or z with probability of Pr(x), Pr(y), Pr(z), all given.  How do I generate a realization of this selection?

Comment: This operation is usually called "sampling".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a function `rand()` that returns a uniform random number in `[0,1]`, then

```
float r = rand();
if (rand < Pr(x)) {
    return x;
} else if (rand < Pr(x)+Pr(y)) {
    return y;
} else {
    return z;
}
```

Similarly, if you can generate a random integer between, say, 1 and 100, then

```
int r = rand();
if (rand < Pr(x)*100) {
    return x;
} else if (rand < (Pr(x)+Pr(y))*100) {
    return y;
} else {
    return z;
}
```

Comment: @Victor: Either that, or it was obvious ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you have probs of events, take function returning normal distrib in [0, 1) and check in which range it falls. If it in [0, 0.3) return A, if it in [0.3, 0.5) return B and otherwise return C.

Answer (score 0):

In python you could write a program which defines a method 'chooser' which takes two parameters px and py those being the probabilties of the first two events occuring independently. The method would return x,y or z as appropriate, python code is below:

```
import random 

def chooser(px,py):
    prob = random.randint(1, 10)
    if (prob<=(px*10)):
        return x
    else if (prob<=((px+py)*10)):
        return y
    else:
        return z
```

Comment: Not quite. You need the second conditional to read `(px+py)*10` in place of `py*10`.